# While implementing thorlabs in python I get TLCameraError: tl_camera_open_sdk() returned error code: 1004 and don't know why

Tags: python, camera

As my title says, I try to implement thorlabs Camera in python, and for that I use the python code provided by thorlabs:

```
"""
Camera Live View - TkInter

This example shows how one could create a live image viewer using TkInter.
It also uses the third party library 'pillow', which is a fork of PIL.

This example detects if a camera is a color camera and will process the
images using the tl_mono_to_color_processor module.

This example uses threading to enqueue images coming off the camera in one thread, and
dequeue them in the UI thread for quick displaying.

"""

import os
os.add_dll_directory(os.getcwd())

try:
    # if on Windows, use the provided setup script to add the DLLs folder to the PATH
    from windows_setup import configure_path
    configure_path()
except ImportError:
    configure_path = None


from sdk.thorlabs_tsi_sdk.tl_camera import TLCameraSDK, TLCamera, Frame
from sdk.thorlabs_tsi_sdk.tl_camera_enums import SENSOR_TYPE
from sdk.thorlabs_tsi_sdk.tl_mono_to_color_processor import MonoToColorProcessorSDK

try:
    #  For python 2.7 tkinter is named Tkinter
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import typing
import threading
try:
    #  For Python 2.7 queue is named Queue
    import Queue as queue
except ImportError:
    import queue

""" LiveViewCanvas

This is a Tkinter Canvas object that can be reused in custom programs. The Canvas expects a parent Tkinter object and 
an image queue. The image queue is a queue.Queue that it will pull images from, and is expected to hold PIL Image 
objects that will be displayed to the canvas. It automatically adjusts its size based on the incoming image dimensions.

"""


class LiveViewCanvas(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, parent, image_queue):
        # type: (typing.Any, queue.Queue) -> LiveViewCanvas
        self.image_queue = image_queue
        self._image_width = 0
        self._image_height = 0
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        self._get_image()

    def _get_image(self):
        try:
            image = self.image_queue.get_nowait()
            self._image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(master=self, image=image)
            if (self._image.width() != self._image_width) or (self._image.height() != self._image_height):
                # resize the canvas to match the new image size
                self._image_width = self._image.width()
                self._image_height = self._image.height()
                self.config(width=self._image_width, height=self._image_height)
            self.create_image(0, 0, image=self._image, anchor='nw')
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
        self.after(10, self._get_image)


""" ImageAcquisitionThread

This class derives from threading.Thread and is given a TLCamera instance during initialization. When started, the 
thread continuously acquires frames from the camera and converts them to PIL Image objects. These are placed in a 
queue.Queue object that can be retrieved using get_output_queue(). The thread doesn't do any arming or triggering, 
so users will still need to setup and control the camera from a different thread. Be sure to call stop() when it is 
time for the thread to stop.

"""


class ImageAcquisitionThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, camera):
        # type: (TLCamera) -> ImageAcquisitionThread
        super(ImageAcquisitionThread, self).__init__()
        self._camera = camera
        self._previous_timestamp = 0

        # setup color processing if necessary
        if self._camera.camera_sensor_type != SENSOR_TYPE.BAYER:
            # Sensor type is not compatible with the color processing library
            self._is_color = False
        else:
            self._mono_to_color_sdk = MonoToColorProcessorSDK()
            self._image_width = self._camera.image_width_pixels
            self._image_height = self._camera.image_height_pixels
            self._mono_to_color_processor = self._mono_to_color_sdk.create_mono_to_color_processor(
                SENSOR_TYPE.BAYER,
                self._camera.color_filter_array_phase,
                self._camera.get_color_correction_matrix(),
                self._camera.get_default_white_balance_matrix(),
                self._camera.bit_depth
            )
            self._is_color = True

        self._bit_depth = camera.bit_depth
        self._camera.image_poll_timeout_ms = 0  # Do not want to block for long periods of time
        self._image_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=2)
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()

    def get_output_queue(self):
        # type: (type(None)) -> queue.Queue
        return self._image_queue

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()

    def _get_color_image(self, frame):
        # type: (Frame) -> Image
        # verify the image size
        width = frame.image_buffer.shape[1]
        height = frame.image_buffer.shape[0]
        if (width != self._image_width) or (height != self._image_height):
            self._image_width = width
            self._image_height = height
            print("Image dimension change detected, image acquisition thread was updated")
        # color the image. transform_to_24 will scale to 8 bits per channel
        color_image_data = self._mono_to_color_processor.transform_to_24(frame.image_buffer,
                                                                         self._image_width,
                                                                         self._image_height)
        color_image_data = color_image_data.reshape(self._image_height, self._image_width, 3)
        # return PIL Image object
        return Image.fromarray(color_image_data, mode='RGB')

    def _get_image(self, frame):
        # type: (Frame) -> Image
        # no coloring, just scale down image to 8 bpp and place into PIL Image object
        scaled_image = frame.image_buffer >> (self._bit_depth - 8)
        return Image.fromarray(scaled_image)

    def run(self):
        while not self._stop_event.is_set():
            try:
                frame = self._camera.get_pending_frame_or_null()
                if frame is not None:
                    if self._is_color:
                        pil_image = self._get_color_image(frame)
                    else:
                        pil_image = self._get_image(frame)
                    self._image_queue.put_nowait(pil_image)
            except queue.Full:
                # No point in keeping this image around when the queue is full, let's skip to the next one
                pass
            except Exception as error:
                print("Encountered error: {error}, image acquisition will stop.".format(error=error))
                break
        print("Image acquisition has stopped")
        if self._is_color:
            self._mono_to_color_processor.dispose()
            self._mono_to_color_sdk.dispose()


""" Main

When run as a script, a simple Tkinter app is created with just a LiveViewCanvas widget. 

"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with TLCameraSDK() as sdk:
        camera_list = sdk.discover_available_cameras()
        with sdk.open_camera(camera_list[0]) as camera:

            # create generic Tk App with just a LiveViewCanvas widget
            print("Generating app...")
            root = tk.Tk()
            root.title(camera.name)
            image_acquisition_thread = ImageAcquisitionThread(camera)
            camera_widget = LiveViewCanvas(parent=root, image_queue=image_acquisition_thread.get_output_queue())

            print("Setting camera parameters...")
            camera.frames_per_trigger_zero_for_unlimited = 0
            camera.arm(2)
            camera.issue_software_trigger()

            print("Starting image acquisition thread...")
            image_acquisition_thread.start()

            print("App starting")
            root.mainloop()

            print("Waiting for image acquisition thread to finish...")
            image_acquisition_thread.stop()
            image_acquisition_thread.join()

            print("Closing resources...")

    print("App terminated. Goodbye!")
```

and I always get the following error message:

`TLCameraError: tl_camera_open_sdk() returned error code: 1004`

I tried to look for what this error could be, but I couldn't find anything about it, and I don't understand it at all. I didn't change anything from the provided code. This error occured when the program tried to use tl_camera.py from thorlabs_tsi_sdk.